# Split name by using _ and call using php

Tags: php, image, split, filenames

i want to split a files name in to two for accessing it through a loop using php 
eg ; image_apple.jpg, image_mango.jpg , image_grapes.jpg etc

and there is a description file correspomding to each image files

eg: description_apple.txt

all these files are in same folder .

i want to show all images and thire curresponding description file in ma web page

someone pls help me 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<?php
$files = scandir("./"); //./ is the current directory

foreach($files as $file) {
    $info = explode('_', $file); //Split on _

    //Skip all files withouth description
    if (count($info) <= 1) {
        continue;
    }

    $info = explode('.', $info['1']); //Split on .

    //Is there a file with description info?
    if (file_exists('description_' . $info['0'] . '.txt')) {
        $description = file_get_contents('description_' . $info['0'] . '.txt'); //$description contains the file description
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if ($handle = opendir('/folder path here/')) {



    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

    $names=explode("_",pathinfo($entry)['filename']);
    echo " desc: description_".$names[0].".txt";echo " name: image_".$names[1].".jpg";
        echo "<br>";
    }



    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: The description is in a description file description_%name%.txt not in the file name itself.

Comment: It still doesn't load the description file, you only echo the filename of the description file.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom once I get a files name, the format of description file is description_filename.txt and image file is image_filename.jpg. Isnt it?